# why does this sed edit break the oneliner?

Tags: bash, sed

I am having trouble with a sed edit. When I run:

```
close=`curl 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/INTC?p=INTC&.tsrc=fin-srch'|html2text|sed -n '/Add to watchlist/,$p'|sed -n '/At close\:/q;p'|head -n-1|tail -n+3`; echo $close
```

I get: `45.60+0.21 (+0.46%)`

But when I add an additional sed command, to strip away everything but the floating number before either the first `+` or `-`, like so:

```
close=`curl 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/INTC?p=INTC&.tsrc=fin-srch'|html2text|sed -n '/Add to watchlist/,$p'|sed -n '/At close\:/q;p'|head -n-1|tail -n+3|sed -n '/^\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)[+-].*$/\1/'`; echo $close
```

my output (echo) is empty. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: `sed -n`? Why `-n`?

Comment: because the result should pipe instead of print

Comment: If it's not printing anything, there's nothing to pipe.

Comment: So really what you're trying to debug is `echo '45.60+0.21 (+0.46%)' | sed -n '/^\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)[+-].*$/\1/'`

Comment: The `-n` has nothing to do with piping instead of printing. It tells `sed` only to generate output if there's an explicit print instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the entire pipeline

```
curl ... |
    html2text|
    sed -n '/Add to watchlist/,/At close/s/^\([0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\)[-+].*/\1/p'
```

If you have GNU `sed` you can simplify the expression a little by using its more powerful RE engine

```
sed -rn '/Add to watchlist/,/At close/s/^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[-+].*/\1/p'
```

The `sed` command looks only on lines *including and between* "`Add to watchlist`" and "`At close`". In that range it looks for a string comprising one or more digits, a dot, and one or more digits, such that it is followed by either `+` or `-`.